# Why is it not compiling in Dev C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This gives a compile error in C++. How can you resolve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>


{
int year,month,day;
};
```

Comment: Your compiler does not support it.

Comment: Please provide the compiler error. What you have doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: @ShowMan The code you linked makes no sense due to invalid syntax and we still don't know what your error is. Please update information to allow a proper answer or delete/answer/flag your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be that the compiler is not seeing the included header file.
for statement `#include <conio.h>` make sure your `conio.h` header file is in your compilers directory. else you can use `#include "conio.h"` and place the header file conio.h in the current project directory.

This header declares several useful library functions for performing "console input and output" from a program. Most C compilers that target DOS, Windows 3.x, Phar Lap, DOSX, OS/2, or Win32 have this header and supply the associated library functions in the default C library. Most C compilers that target UNIX and Linux do not have this header and do not supply the library functions.

Comment: Sorry I left out some parts there. Can you check this now.

Answer (score 0):

Is it supposed to be a function? If it is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

int main() 
{
    int month, year, day;
}
```

Compiles and works perfectly fine on my side.

Comment: I missed some parts. Sorry for that. Now can you check this.

Comment: Uuuuh... Wait. Now i'm totally confused. Is your { int year.month,day; } supposed to be a function a structure a class a what?

Comment: If it is supposed to be a function, that works fine on my side. I can compile no problem.